# SoapUI: getting a "404 not found" even if my request works in browser

Tags: api, soapui

I have a problem with some requests that returns a 404 in SoapUI but when I try them in the browser it works!
Is there any reason for that to happen? Sorry I'm new to API testing

Comment: This is information not really helps unless if you dig into and find some more details. Or need some way to be able to reproduce for others.

Comment: The request does work and I just want to convert some old working requests into a SoapUI project because we used an old tool. That is why I don't have much details but want to know what is causing this? Maybe there is a requirement in SoapUI before testing a raw request